# Why can't i access JAX-RS api?

Tags: jax-rs, java

I have a task from a company, that send me a virtual machine with everything set up. The task is that i have to create an API to retrieve Person details from the database and display it.

The problem is that when i run the application, the server returns an index.html with hello world text in it. However, when i try to change the index.html, it does not change in the browser, but when i do request through postman, i get the "updated" index.html.

What i also realised that i cannot access the API that i have created, to check if i can access APIs in the first place.

The path where the index.html returns is "http://hocalhost:8080/tutorial-applicans/"

My Service is PersonService.java:

```
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Stateless
@Path("person")
public class PersonService{

@PersistenceContext(unitName = "de.erknrw_tutorial-applicants_pu")
private EntityManager em;

@GET
@Path("hello")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String sayHello(){
return "Hello World!!!"
}


}
```

I am trying to get "Hello World!!!", but my path is wrong, when i tried "http://hocalhost:8080/tutorial-applicans/person/hello".

Might be worth mentioning that there is also a JAXRSConfiguration.java file:

```
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Applications;

@ApplicationPath(JAXRSConfiguration.RESTROOT)
public class JAXRSConfiguration extends Application{

public static final String RESTROOT = "webresources";
}
```

How do access the sayHello()? How does the path look like?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It could just be caching the site.... try opening the browser in incognito

Comment: `http://hocalhost:8080/tutorial-applicans/webresources/person/hello`

Comment: @areus That worked. Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad it worked. I added a response. Consider accepting it if you think it's helpful.

Answer (score 1):

When deploying on a webapp, the JAX-RS application is configured as a Servlet. So, you have to add the application path prior to the path of the resource.

The endpoint would be:

```
http://[server]:[port]/[context path]/[application path]/[resource path]/[operation path]
```

In your case:

```
http://hocalhost:8080/tutorial-applicans/webresources/person/hello
```